# Does union of bit fields make any sense

Tags: c, unions, bit-fields

I recently came across a third party code snippet inside our application that does not make any sense to me. What puzzled me first it that it has been in production for at least 10 years and seemed to work. It is basically a `union` of bit fields:

```
union
{
    unsigned longitude : 2;         //!< status of the longitude (offset: 0)
    unsigned latitude : 2;          //!< status of the latitude (offset: 2)
    unsigned xPosition : 2;         //!< status of the x position relative to starting position (offset: 4)
    unsigned yPosition : 2;         //!< status of the y position relative to starting position (offset: 6)
    // ... Many more 2-bit fields... Total 26 fields
    unsigned reserved : 12;
    unsigned long status[2];            //!< raw status data
} status;
```

I am pretty sure that this is a bug and what the author really wanted to write was:

```
union
{
    struct
    {
        unsigned longitude : 2;         //!< status of the longitude (offset: 0)
        unsigned latitude : 2;          //!< status of the latitude (offset: 2)
        unsigned xPosition : 2;         //!< status of the x position relative to starting position (offset: 4)
        unsigned yPosition : 2;         //!< status of the y position relative to starting position (offset: 6)
        // ... Many more 2-bit fields... Total 26 fields
        unsigned reserved : 12;
    };
    unsigned status[2];         //!< raw status data (should not be long!)
} status;
```

The reason it was kind of working is that only one of those 26 bit fields was actually used!
But this bug made raised a few questions:

- Is the compiler required to use the same first 2 bits of the same `unsigned` for all fields (despite what the comments say)?
- Is there any real usage for a `union` of bit fields? I cannot think of any situation where this would make sense.
- If that doesn't make any sense, how come that no compilers we are using (neither Clang, GCC nor MSVC) were issuing any warning?

Comment: I think you're right about what was intended. But a union of bit fields could still make sense if you want to overlay the different bit fields over the same bits.

Comment: Bit field is just an unsigned integer. Union of bit fields can make just as much sense as union of different size integers.

Comment: I am surprised it is compiling. I was under impression bitfield syntax is only valid within`struct`

Comment: The comments next to each field suggest that it was supposed to be a structure, since they say that each bitfield should be at a different bit offset. A union would put them all at offset 0.

Comment: @EugeneSh. I just looked that up in the specification. Structs and union have identical syntax (but different behavior of course). See section 6.7.2.1.

Comment: @hyde: Bit-fields may be signed. If one is declared `signed int`, it is signed. If it is `int`, it is implementation-defined whether it is signed or not.

Comment: The union may have been intended for: 1) write to the `status` array, and then read individual bit fields, or 2) write to the bit fields, and then read from the `status` array. But neither of those will work as written. I'd search the code to see if the `status` array is being used anywhere.

Comment: @EugeneSh., *and* there is no constraint against unions containing bitfields in the specification text, which is what would have been used if it were intended that unions could not have bitfield members despite that being consistent with the lexical syntax.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Is the compiler required to use the same first 2 bits of the same unsigned for all fields (despite what the comments say)?

No. C 2018 6.7.2.1 says “An implementation may allocate any addressable storage unit large enough to hold a bit-field… The order of allocation of bit-fields within a unit (high-order to low-order or low-order to high-order) is implementation-defined…”

It does not say the addressable storage unit will be the same for all bit-fields of the same size. If it did, then all the union bit-field members of the same size would have to use the same bits, and certainly any reasonable C implementation would do so.

However, consider bit-fields of different sizes. It is reasonable that a compiler would allocate a one-byte storage unit for a bit-field of 2 bits and a four-byte storage unit for a bit-field of 17 bits. If it is a little-endian system and puts the bits in high-order to low-order, then the 2-bit field would be in bits 2<sup>7</sup> and 2<sup>6</sup> of byte 0, and the 17-bit field would be in all bits of bytes 3 and 2 (bits 2<sup>31</sup> to 2<sup>16</sup> of the four-byte little-endian storage unit) and bit 2<sup>7</sup> of byte 1 (bit 2<sup>15</sup> of the storage unit). So there would be no overlap between these two union members.

> Is there any real usage for a union of bit fields? I cannot think of any situation where this would make sense.

Sure, I might have some field in a data structure that sometimes needs to store a 17-bit fromitz number and other times needs to store a 13-bit gizmo number. Unions were originally for storing one thing or another, not for reinterpreting bits of one type as another type.

Answer (score 1):

I was curious so I coded this up.  Certainly this was a bug waiting to happen.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
union
{
    unsigned longitude : 2;         //!< status of the longitude (offset: 0)
    unsigned latitude : 2;          //!< status of the latitude (offset: 2)
    unsigned xPosition : 2;         //!< status of the x position relative to starting position (offset: 4)
    unsigned yPosition : 2;         //!< status of the y position relative to starting position (offset: 6)
    // ... Many more 2-bit fields... Total 26 fields
    unsigned reserved : 12;
    unsigned long status[2];            //!< raw status data
} status;

int main( int argc, char **argv) {
  memset( &status, 0x00, sizeof(status) );
  status.longitude = 0x02;

  printf("Union Size = %lu\n", sizeof(status));
  printf("status.longitude = %x\n", status.longitude );
  printf("status.latitude = %x\n", status.latitude );
}
```

Setting `status.longitude = 0x02;` effectively sets all the other variables in the `ūnion` to the same value.

Output is:

> Union Size = 16

> status.longitude = 2

> status.latitude = 2